# Replace a column value with NULL in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, null

How to replace incorrect column values (values with characters like `*` or `#`) with null?

[image: Screenshot here!]

Comment: But please describe it more. What needs to be replaced to null? If string contains one star? If it is 3 stars? More details are needed

Comment: @ZygD When string contains at least one star.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test dataset:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(10, '2021-08-16 00:54:43+01', 0.15, 'SMS'),
     (11, '2021-08-16 00:04:29+01', 0.15, '*'),
     (12, '2021-08-16 00:39:05+01', 0.15, '***')],
    ['_c0', 'Timestamp', 'Amount','Channel']
)
df.show(truncate=False)
# +---+----------------------+------+-------+
# |_c0|Timestamp             |Amount|Channel|
# +---+----------------------+------+-------+
# |10 |2021-08-16 00:54:43+01|0.15  |SMS    |
# |11 |2021-08-16 00:04:29+01|0.15  |*      |
# |12 |2021-08-16 00:39:05+01|0.15  |***    |
# +---+----------------------+------+-------+
```

Script:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.withColumn('Channel', F.when(~F.col('Channel').rlike(r'[\*#]+'), F.col('Channel')))

df.show(truncate=False)
# +---+----------------------+------+-------+
# |_c0|Timestamp             |Amount|Channel|
# +---+----------------------+------+-------+
# |10 |2021-08-16 00:54:43+01|0.15  |SMS    |
# |11 |2021-08-16 00:04:29+01|0.15  |null   |
# |12 |2021-08-16 00:39:05+01|0.15  |null   |
# +---+----------------------+------+-------+
```

Comment: what "F" does??

(Thank you for your help mate)

Comment: `from pyspark.sql import functions as F` - I have added this line to the code now

Answer (score 0):

So You have multiple choices:

First option is the use the when function to condition the replacement for each character you want to replace:

example: [when function](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-replace-empty-value-with-none-on-dataframe/)

Second option is to use the replace function.

example: [replace function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.replace.html)

third option is to use regex_replace to replace all the characters with null value

example: [regex_replace function](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-regexp_replace-replace-string-value/)